# How to pass hash password from ruby-block to user resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

I am trying to implement a cookbook which would create users by reading passwords from attributes file ( non hash password ex: root@123)

And for this, my cookbook is as follows :

1. **Contents of attributes file** ( attributes/attr.rb )

   ```
   default['my']['instance']['users'] = [
     {uid: 1004,user_name:'m1',homedir:'/home/m1',password:'root@111'}
     {uid: 1003,user_name:'m2',homedir:'/home/m2',password:'root@222'},
     {uid: 1002, user_name:'m3',homedir:'/home/m3',password:'root@333'}
   ]
   ```
2. **Recipe** :

   ```
   password_hash=''
   node['my']['instance']['users'].each do |each_user|
       ruby_block "Generating hash password" do
           block do
               require 'digest/sha2'
               password=each_user['password']
               salt=rand(36**8).to_s(36)
               shadow_hash=password.crypt("$6$" + salt)
               password_hash=shadow_hash
           end
       end

       user each_user['user_name'] do
           password "#{password_hash}"
           home each_user['homedir']
           system true
           action :create
           manage_home true
           uid each_user['uid']
       end
   end
   ```

After execution of the cookbook, respective users are created appropriately but passwords are set blank.

Looks like the variable which I am trying to access in the password attribute of user resource is not correct.

Please let me how can I resolve this.

Note: In my case, I don't want to use databags.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put that code in a ruby_block, just have it in the normal loop and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think using ruby_bloque is a good practice . you just have to inform the provider change the variable .
eg

```
password_hash=''
node['my']['instance']['users'].each do |each_user|
    ruby_block "Generating hash password" do
        block do
            require 'digest/sha2'
            password=each_user['password']
            salt=rand(36**8).to_s(36)
            shadow_hash=password.crypt("$6$" + salt)
            password_hash=shadow_hash
            user_resource = resources("user[#{each_user['user_name']}]")
            user_resource.password password_hash
        end
    end

    user each_user['user_name'] do
        password "#{password_hash}"
        home each_user['homedir']
        system true
        action :create
        manage_home true
        uid each_user['uid']
    end
end
```

sorry for my english.
Best regards.

Comment: I may be missing something, but I'm pretty sure each user will end up with the same password as the ruby_block is named the same on each iteration. Naming it `Generating hash password for #{each_user['user_name']}` should do the trick.

Comment: The only resource that should not repeat name, is the resource user, so that the code works. But if we make the change you suggest we avoid the warn (CHEF-3694).
I test the code with test-kitchen
Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

The password_hash variable is local scope to your ruby block, and thus not accessible in the user block.  You can actually move all that ruby for creating the hash directly into the use block.

Comment: These lines send the hash_password variable, to resource user
`user_resource = resources("user[#{each_user['user_name']}]")
user_resource.password password_hash`